# How to properly display a HUD on a SpriteKit game across different resolutions?

Tags: swift, position

I originally created my game with iOS 8 and tested on my iPhone 6S. The game looks fine in the 5, 5S, 6, 6 Plus, 6S, and 6S Plus (since all devices have the same ratio of 16:9). As you can see from the image, the music button is offset from the top right corner. The image is offset by this code:

```
 muteButton.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) + 920, y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) + 480)
```

[image]

The problem I have is if someone tried this game on an iPad, it will display this. As you can see, the bottom graphic and the mute button are offset from the sides by a lot.

[image]

I want to make it so that the objects will always stay close to the sides of the frame/view. Making the app "universal" on xCode does not fix it either. Or do I just make a completely new project built for the iPad?

Comment: Don't edit your question with a solution. Post it as an answer instead.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that.

Comment: Take out the "Solution:..." text from your question, and post it in the "Your Answer" box at the bottom of the page. Then you can get lots for your solution.

Comment: Done! I thought it was weird to answer it myself.

Comment: your game looks good on my iPhone 4S, but performance is poor due to rescaling the huge images.

Comment: It manages to work on an iPhone 4S? I didn't think it could handle iOS 9 since my game requires iOS 9 and above. But thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## **Solution! I figured it out! For those who come from the future and also might need help with this. This works with landscape orientation and portrait orientation.**

**Note: You must have your scene.scaleMode set to .AspectFill for this to work on all scenes and the scene size has to be 2048x1536 or 1536x2048. This will make it scaleable for iPad too.**

I have declared the following variable on the top of my class.

```
class StartScene: SKScene {
     let playableArea: CGRect
}
```

Then, I have the following code inside the override init() function.

```
override init(size: CGSize) {

    //1. Get the aspect ratio of the device
    let deviceWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width
    let deviceHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height
    let maxAspectRatio: CGFloat = deviceWidth / deviceHeight

    //2. For landscape orientation, use this*****
    let playableHeight = size.width / maxAspectRatio
    let playableMargin = (size.height - playableHeight) / 2.0
    playableArea = CGRect(x: 0, y: playableMargin, width: size.width, height: playableHeight)

    //3. For portrait orientation, use this*****
    let playableWidth = size.height / maxAspectRatio
    let playableMargin = (size.width - playableWidth) / 2.0
    playableArea = CGRect(x: playableMargin, y: 0, width: playableWidth, height: size.height)

    super.init(size: size)
}
```

From here, I then use the variable playableArea to position my objects.

```
titleChild.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(playableArea), y: CGRectGetMaxY(playableArea) - (titleChild.size.height * 0.90))
```

Works amazing. Looks good in the iPhone 4S, 5, 5S, 6, 6 Plus, 6S, 6S Plus, and iPads.

If you want to see the box in the app to make sure you did it right, use the following function.

```
func drawPlayableArea() {
    let shape = SKShapeNode()
    let path = CGPathCreateMutable()
    CGPathAddRect(path, nil, playableArea)
    shape.path = path
    shape.strokeColor = SKColor.redColor()
    shape.lineWidth = 8
    addChild(shape)
}
```

Then just call the function in the didMoveToView() function to view the red frame to make sure you did the code right. This will create a red frame the size of the view that is viewable to the user. Now that you have playableArea to hold the frame that the user can see, you can use it for other things such as making sure objects don't or can't leave the bounds, etc. For this screenshot, I use it to prevent the user from moving the spaceship outside the device.

[image]

Comment: You dont need to set your scene to 2048x1536, since all this does is force your scene into 4:3, any number coordinates can be used.  Also you are altering your scene space  so now your coordinates are different on screen  depending on device and you need to account, which may not be a desired result for some people.  For instance, both ipad and iphone 4s are 4x3,  You are making the iPad play resolution game space the 1024x768,  but on ipod it will be 480x320,  which will render differently

Comment: Which is why the ratio is determined in the code of the device. I've already implemented this in my game that works across all devices. 2048x1536 does not force the scene into 4:3 because it's aspect filled, meaning a section of the background will be show in the middle of non-iPad devices. You're thinking that the 2046x1536 backgounds gets squashed into the scene but it doesn't. You can see it in my screenshots.

Comment: no,  I am referring to the scene game area,  not talking about the scaling factors

Comment: your scenes coordinate system if you will

Comment: oh wait,  I missed a step,  your override init,  is that filling size in at 2048x1536?

Comment: Because it's aspect filled, making the scenes 2048x1536 will allow it to work on iPads well. If you open the app on a non-iPad device, everything still fits the scene in relation to the playable area. The only thing that does not scale down is the background. Yes, but the size is determined before moving to the scene. let scene = GameScene(size: CGSize(width: 2048, height: 1536))

Comment: Normally I just set the size in the sprite kits builder, so if you are creating the scene that way, than your issue is now on smaller devices things will be super tiny,  how do you compensate for that part.  BTW, making it aspect fill does nothing on iPad,  you are already at 4:3, so no scaling is done to the scene.  The scaling gets done on 16:9 devices, so you end up losing the thiner sides of your graphics

Comment: things are not super tiny on small devices, they are okay. Like I said, I've already applied this on 2 games that I have, and 1 of them is universal and is in the app store: Chomp'd.

Comment: maybe I am missing something here,  right now I see your play area is 2048x1536.  how do these numbers get smaller for smaller devices?

Comment: Okay, so the size is 2048x1536 so it can be displayed on iPads correct. When the device is smaller, and because it's aspect filled, the entire 2048x1536 does not get squished to the smaller screen. Since the playable area rectangle is formed by the device ratio that the game is running on, the objects will display appropriately on the right position on all devices since the playable area rectangle is formed by getting the device's ratio and size.

Comment: It's not that it get's smaller, but because the screen is smaller, the device already automatically renders the sprites smaller. The reason the backgrounds (at least for me) don't get squished into the scene is because the backgrounds are sized at 2048 by 1536. The sprite size is relative to the size of the device. On iPad, the sprites are bigger.

Comment: I mean, maybe the size doesn't need to be 2048x1536 or aspect filled, but I haven't tested it out with different sizes and fills yet so I don't know if it will work in those properties, but I know it works in 2048x1536 aspect filled.

Comment: ok, so you are wasting texture memory then on the smaller devices when it isn't needed, and trusting the device to scale for you.  This is a good note to others who may look at this, because this is not a desired result for everybody,  I myself would not like the hardware to do the scaling for me like this unless it is necessary,  it is one of the reasons why we have retina and non retina style graphics.  Not saying it is wrong,  just not everybody codes like this that is all.

Comment: Only the backgrounds, which could easily be fixed by changing the background texture by detecting the screen ratio. The game graphics are actually sized for iPads. When they are generated on smaller devices, they are resized by the device themselves, which still makes them look good. Do you have a different sprite for each different size? Is that what you're saying? Must be terrible to manage that.

Comment: no, I normally have one set of sprites(@1x,@2x,@3x),  but I design for the phone in mind, not iPad,  and depending on what my needs are,  will do a scale up at a 2x  scale rate with a slightly larger game worldview ,have the game world just show more information,  or generate an @4x image and have the drawing mechanics handle it some how since it is not supported on device.  It is all based on designer preference of course,  but since the iPad is a 2.13 scale from iPhone,  things could look distorted like fat lines skinny lines,  so i always try to watch out for stuff like this

Comment: I only need 1 sprite and it works for all devices. I don't need to calculate scales, etc. My game Chomp'd, is for iPad, iPhones, and iPods. The sprite sizes are scaled down automatically since it's aspect filled, and it still looks good. The sprite's initial size are designed for the iPad. To each his own.

Comment: exactly,  the point is really not for you,  but others looking at this and wondering why things are not working out correctly,  that is all

Comment: Well, my code works if you want to make a game for iPhones and iPad compatibility. I wouldn't say it's completely useful only to me.

Comment: ok this is the last thing I am going to say then I am done,  if you want to take an iPad game, and squish it into an iPhone's resolution, use the answer  verbatim, otherwise read the comments to help figure out why your app is not looking as good as expected

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget about the 4s,  you will get the same problems as iPad.  SpriteKit does not have constraints like in the UI builder,  so you are going to have to accommodate for the 4:3 and the 16:9 devices by applying some math,  or force the 4:3 to be 16:9 with black borders using the .AspectFit scaling method.

Now I am not sure where 920, and 480 are coming from, but those numbers may have to be tweaked in this code when detecting the device.  Simplest way to determine your aspect ration is to do `UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width/UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height`,  then work from there.

Comment: Thank you! Works perfect on all devices now.